# Adding multi-language support to web app from the start

Tags: internationalization

I'm about to start a PHP/MySQL based web app and before I start coding I wanted to know how do I incorporate multi-language support? I figured I should develop with the international audience in mind from the start rather than as an after thought (which most likely will cause slow roll outs to international regions due to having to figure out how to add multi-language support to the web app).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at i18n. Here is some link: http://conferences.oreillynet.com/presentations/mysql06/winstead_practical.pdf